# Django models: set default IntegerField to number of instances

Tags: python, django-models

I would like to set the "order" IntegerField of my Achievement model to the current count of objects in Achievement. The order field is used to order achievements, and users can change it. For now I have 1 as default.

```
class Achievement(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    order = models.IntegerField(default=1)   #Get the number of achievement objects
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'achievement'
        ordering = ['order', 'id']
```

For example, if I already have one achievement in my database with whatever order the next one should get order=2 by default.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here.  Your ordering here is based on `order` first and then `id`. Sounds like that's what you want

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you want to have a default value of `1` to the `order` integer field and increment it with each entry of `Achievment` (same functionality as the `id`), but also allow users change it.

For this purpose you can use Django's [`AutoField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.AutoField):

> An `IntegerField` that automatically increments according to available IDs. You usually won’t need to use this directly; a primary key field will automatically be added to your model if you don’t specify otherwise.

Like this:

```
class Achievement(models.Model):
    ...

    order = models.AutoField(default=1, primary_key=False)
    # Also specify that this autofield is *not* a ^ primary key

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order', 'id']
```

Comment: I get AssertionError: A model can't have more than one AutoField.
If I do primary_key=True I get errors with the existing id's